# Updating a single dependency with Composer

Tags: composer-php

I'm using Composer and upon the last install, got the message:

> Package guzzle/guzzle is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use
>   guzzlehttp/guzzle instead.

I went to my composer.lock file and saw that some of my packages were using guzzle/guzzle while other packages were using guzzlehttp/guzzle:

```
"require-dev": {
                "amphp/artax": "*@dev",
                "ext-curl": "*",
                "guzzle/guzzle": "*",
```

A few questions come to mind:

1. Is there any way to update those packages with guzzlehttp/guzzle?
2. And if I did do this, wouldn't it be possible that the packages which use guzzle/guzzle no longer qorks?
3. Would the best course of action be to wait for the package author to change the dependency to guzzlehttp/guzzle and then re-install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way is to wait for the original package author to change that and then update that package in your project.

A way for you to change it yourself could be to fork that package and test all the stuff yourself.

But I see no need to change that if your project works fine. It's just a message that `guzzle/guzzle` is no longer maintained, but that doesn't mean that it is not working anymore. Just a *suggestion* to use `guzzlehttp/guzzle` as this is the latest maintained version now.